# Need help with understanding manipulations on logarithms

Tags: logarithms

I cannot understand the result from logarithms manipulations even though I am going over logarithmic properties. I am simply stuck.
So here is the problem:
$$n = 2^k \implies k = \log_2n$$
$$x = 3^k \implies k = \log_3x$$
$$\log_2n = \frac{\log_3n}{\log_32}$$
$$\log_3x = \log_3n^{1.59}$$

I do not understand how we got the last line of the solution! I understand it must be very simple to understand, but I am stuck with it. I will be thankful for help.

Comment: I bet that $\log_23\approx1.59$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\log_3x = \frac{\log_3 n}{\log_3 2} = 1.59 \log_3 n$$

Because $\frac{1}{\log_3 2} = 1.59$ and use that $c\log_a b = \log_ab^{c}$.